# Ambiguous use of 'xxx'

Tags: swift

```
func doSomething(a:Int) {}

let var1 = doSomething // ok

// Only the label is different
func somethingElse(a:Int) {}
func somethingElse(b:Int) {}

let var2 = somethingElse // Ambiguous use of 'somethingElse'
```

I don't know how to deal with this problem. Please help me! How do I choose to use `somethingElse(a:Int)`  or `somethingElse(b:Int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to write the label explicitly.
Here's an example

```swift
func doSomething(a:Int) {
    print("do something with \(a)")
}

func somethingElse(a:Int) {
    print("do something else with \(a)")
}
func somethingElse(b:Int) {
    print("do something else with \(b)")
}

let var1 = doSomething(a:)
let var2 = somethingElse(a:)
let var3 = somethingElse(b:)

var1(1)
var2(2)
var3(3)
```